# Additional many to many relations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

is there any way in Laravel 5 to make our `belongsToMany()` method get more relations than described in pivot table? I'd like to have my `$user->movies()` method retrieve movies assigned to the user **and all movies with `access` column set to `public`**. Is that possible without manual query?

I tried this:

```
public function movies() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie')->orWhere('access', 'public')->withTimestamps();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible this way. You can do this though:

```
$userId = 1;
$movies = App\Movie::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($userId){
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
})->orWhere('access', 'public')->get();
```

---

You can put the whole thing inside your `User` model inside an attribute accessor but you won't be able to eager load it.

```
public function getAvailableMoviesAttribute(){
    $userId = $this->getKey();
    $movies = App\Movie::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($userId){
        $q->where('user_id', $userId);
    })->orWhere('access', 'public')->get();
    return $movies;
}
```

Usage:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->availableMovies;
```

---

To be able to do more filtering you can use a "normal" function in your model and just return the query without calling `get()`

```
public function movies(){
    $userId = $this->getKey();
    return App\Movie::whereHas('users', function($q) use ($userId){
        $q->where('user_id', $userId);
    })->orWhere('access', 'public');
}
```

Usage:

```
$user->movies()->where('title', 'LIKE', B%')->get()
```

**Note** that now `movies` isn't a relationship anymore. It's just a function that returns a query builder instance.

Comment: Any chance to some other, more model-based solution?

Comment: Not really. I'd like it to behave exactly like `belongsToMany()`, so I'd like to be able to query it further, like `$user->movies()->where('title', 'LIKE', 'B%')->get()` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this solution. It's not 100% satisfactory, but there's no better I believe.